# Get intersection of 2 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
    Id   MedId  ShipId  AvailableQuant  DefaultQuant  MinQuant  MedExpiry                       LastUsed  
------  ------  ------  --------------  ------------  --------  -------------------  ---------------------
 1       1    2918              20            30        15  2015-02-05 11:37:24    2014-12-01 11:37:32
 4       2    2918              50            55        30  2015-03-26 11:57:14    2014-12-03 11:57:22
 5       3    2918              15            40        20  2014-12-10 16:58:58    2014-12-10 16:59:02
 6       4    2918              30            75        30  2015-03-31 11:58:26    2014-12-03 11:58:32
 7       5    2918              22            50        20  2015-01-01 11:59:05    2014-12-03 11:59:09
 9       6    3095               5            35        10  2014-12-03 11:59:51    2014-09-01 11:59:55
10       7    2918              30            60        35  2014-12-01 12:00:43    2014-10-22 12:00:57
11       8    3095              25            30        20  2014-12-31 17:48:58    2014-12-01 17:49:12
```

And there are 2 queries that i have written

1)To give me count of critical Items

```
SELECT  SUM(IF(m.AvailableQuant <= m.MinQuant,1, 0)) AS criticalFROM tbl_vesselmaster vs
INNER JOIN comp_login cl ON vs.co_id = cl.id
INNER JOIN m_shipinv m ON vs.id = m.ShipId
WHERE vs.co_id=$co_id;
```

2)To give me medicine that have excedeed expiry date

```
SELECT COUNT(MedId) as count FROM `m_shipinv` WHERE DATE(MedExpiry) < DATE(NOW());
```

i want a query to get the count intersection of this both query. means if the item is critical and its medicine is expired then it should count only 1

this should be the output

```
count
-------
4
```

Comment: I think the solution is to combine the two queries. Maybe you should have a try first?

Comment: i have tried it. but mysql does not support 'intersect'.

Comment: Rewrite it as one query.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match all of the column names you've shown in your query, so it's very difficult for anyone to understand what you're really looking for and how you got 4 as expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just add the `where` clause to the first query:

```
SELECT SUM(m.AvailableQuant <= m.MinQuant) AS critical
FROM tbl_vesselmaster vs INNER JOIN
     comp_login cl
     ON vs.co_id = cl.id INNER JOIN
     m_shipinv m
     ON vs.id = m.ShipId
WHERE vs.co_id = $co_id OR DATE(MedExpiry) < DATE(NOW());
```

Note that I simplified the `SUM()` calculation.  The `if` is not needed because MySQL treats booleans as integers in a numeric context.

Comment: but it is only showing me the count from ship 2918 and not from the  ship 3095. I want to get total from both vessels

Comment: Thanx Bro that worked !! i added another condition also m.AvailableQuant <= m.MinQuant in the end with 'OR' condition.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put the two conditions in the where clause ?
I don't understand all you inner joins as you only describe one table. I just altered the select of Gordon Linoff:

```
SELECT count(*) AS critical
FROM tbl_vesselmaster vs 
       INNER JOIN comp_login cl ON vs.co_id = cl.id 
       INNER JOIN m_shipinv m   ON vs.id = m.ShipId
WHERE vs.co_id = $co_id 
  AND DATE(MedExpiry) < DATE(NOW())
  AND m.availableQuant <= m.minQuant;
```

I think the result should be 3: only records 5, 9 and 10 meet both criteria.